# Kubernetes External Service not honoring port

Tags: kubernetes, service, port

I created a service to our database like below. I was expecting a connection string like mysql://database/schema would connect to that database on port 18000, however it still used the default 3306 port.

```
 apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: database
    spec:
      type: ExternalName
      externalName: mysql.database.com
      ports:
        - port: 18000
```

I was able to fix this by using mysql://database:18000/schema, but wondering if anyone can tell me what actual purpose of the port on the service is? It doesn't really seem to use it for anything in this case.

Would have thought either the service would enforce using port 18000 in the connection string, or more helpfully remove the need to specify a port at all and reach out the external database on port 18000. Doesn't seem to either, in fact seems totally useless to add a port to the external service at all.

Comment: Thank you for your question. Questions focused specifically on Kubernetes, such as configuring or deploying a cluster, may be better answered by the experts in either the [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/). These platforms are highly knowledgeable in Kubernetes and can provide comprehensive support tailored to your needs. As a reminder, all questions on Stack Overflow must be specifically related to programming. We appreciate your understanding and encourage you to visit the "on-topic" pages of either site before posting there to ensure a more relevant and helpful response.